# Run stored procedure on linked server (linked server name as Parameter)

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters, wherescape-red

I'm trying to execute code against linked server which is coming from a parameter. Below is my code. However I get an error:

> 'Could not find server 'P_LINKED_SERVER'.

How does one execute against server which is coming from a parameter?

```
DECLARE @P_LINKED_SERVER AS VARCHAR(30)

SET @LINKED_SERVER = (SELECT DSS_PARAMETER_VALUE FROM [DBO].DSS_PARAMETER WHERE DSS_PARAMETER_NAME = 'Server Name')
DECLARE @sql AS VARCHAR(max)

SET @sql = 'SQL CODE'

EXEC (@sql) AT [@P_LINKED_SERVER];
```

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The linked server name has to be part of the complete statement and cannot be a parameter.  So:

```
DECLARE @P_LINKED_SERVER AS VARCHAR(30);

SELECT @LINKED_SERVER = DSS_PARAMETER_VALUE
FROM [DBO].DSS_PARAMETER
WHERE DSS_PARAMETER_NAME = 'Server Name';

DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(max);

SET @sql = CONCAT('EXEC SQL CODE AT ', @LINKED_SERVER);

EXEC(@sql);
```

In your case, you seem to want:

```
SET @sql = CONCAT('EXEC ''DELETE FROM tablename'' AT ', @LINKED_SERVER);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, the above comes back with error ' Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DELETE'.'  SET @sql = CONCAT('EXEC DELETE FROM TABLENAME ', @LINKED_SERVER)

Comment: You need single quotes around the statement.